Visual Studio 2022 - Problem with Instrumentation tool
I need to use the instrumentation of Visual Studio 2022 (17.10).
I set the /PROFILE option in the linker, but when starting the profiling, I see in the output windows the following error:

'GameOfLife' failed to launch. Failed to instrument
"C:\Users\399\Desktop\GameOfLife\GameOfLife\x64\Debug\GameOfLife.exe".
VsInstr exited with code -1073741819

After the running the program, VS tells me that there are no data to show (only CPU and memory usage). So, I can't see the % usage of each functions, etc.
I tried making a new MFC project, with all default values at its creation.
I changed the linker option top /PROFILE and then the instrumentation tool is working correctly.
I wonder why it works for that last project but not the previous one.
Please help.

VsInstr and MSVC have an intimate (and undocumented) relationship. VsInstr can instrument only binaries that were entirely compiled with MSVC. Does your project link a static library that wasn't built with MSVC or are you compiling part of the code using a different compiler?

Just one exe generated with visual studio (no linked libraries/dlls). After doint the instrumentation with the new project, I retried with the one that was giving me error and now, instrumentation works correctly.
